# Checking where all Foreign key is being used

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Lets say there's a table Table1 with Primary key as "MainID" and this MainID is being used as a Foreign key in many tables.

Now when I try and delete a record from Table1 who's MainID as foreign key is being used in some child tables, then it throws this exception that "Foreign key conflict n stuff"..

Now I want to design my Delete Strored procedure in such a way that first of all checks ALL the child t ables that have that foreign key column "MainID" and if MainID from Table1 is being used in any of the child tables it should return 0 . Based on this 0 value I want an alert box to show that will say "Still in use or watever" and wont let the user delete that record unless ALL the records in child tables have been deleted that were using that mainID from table1.

I can't use ON DELETE CASCADE. I want the user to delete child table records manually one by one. Only after child table records using the MainID have been deleted that the user can delete record from Table1

Answer (score 2):

I would consider using TRY/CATCH (in c# or SQL Server) to trap the correct SQL error number.

It's straightforward to drill into system table and find the links, but then it's several dynamic queries one for each child table.

Comment: +1 Catching this in ASP.NET C# is definitely the best; use Exception.Number to check if it's a foreign key violation